# How to fetch all photos from Facebook in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an application in which I am using Facebook SDK for different purposes. Currently I have implemented Login through Facebook. Now my next task is to fetch all the photos of the logged in user and display all of them in a grid. I am following the official facebook developer website as a reference for this task. Following is the code that I am using to fetch the user photos.

```
    new Request(
            Session.getActiveSession(),
            "/me/photos",
            getRequestParameters(),
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    /* handle the result */
                    Log.d("Response ","Response " + response);
                    mpBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        ).executeAsync();

private Bundle getRequestParameters() 
    {
        String accessToken = LoginSigbUpCustomerNew.mytoken;
           Bundle parameters = new Bundle(1);
           parameters.putString("access_token", accessToken);
           return parameters;
    }
```

Here, I am getting response like this :-

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"data":[]}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}
```

I cant understand why the data array is empty. Also I am requesting the user_photos permission from user. So where the thing is wrong.
I am new to this Facebook SDK and dont know how to solve this. If anyone can help me it would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Salman, Can you post some code for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to request your photos is just fine according to the documentation of Facebook SDK however I think that you forgot to request permission from the user who's logged in (you in this case).

Copied from Facebook SDK documentation: `A user access token with user_photos permission is required to see all photos that person is tagged in or has uploaded.`

The following link gives you a small tutorial on how to add access tokens to the login button: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.2?locale=en_GB#step3

In your case it would be (code snippet is for activities only, for fragments: click the url above and follow the tutorial there. Pretty straight forward):

```
...
LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.ID_OF_YOUR_LOGIN_BUTTON);
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_photos"));
...
```

In your overriding onCreate method.

---

**Method two:**

```
...
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
    session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
        .setPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_photos"))
        .setCallback(YOUR_CALLBACK_CLASS_VARIABLE));
} else {
    // Open an active session. Basically happens when someone is already logged in.
}
...
```

Before making the call to request all the user photos, you can simply open a new request when the user hasn't logged in yet. This can happen in `View.OnClickListener` class of a `Button` as it seems that you're not LoginButton of Facebook.

`YOUR_CALLBACK_CLASS_VARIABLE` is your class implementing Session.StatusCallback. I'm quite certain you know what it is and what it does.

---

**Method three:**

```
...
    Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
      .NewPermissionsRequest(this, Arrays.asList("user_photos"));
    session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
...
```

When the user is already logged in (**so after the user is logged in**) and you wish to request additional permissions from the user to access his photos or whatsoever. This is by the way all written in the docs of Facebook SDK for Android.

For more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.2?locale=en_GB#step3

Comment: Hey @kevto thanks for the answer but I am not using Login Button for Facebook Login. Then how can I do this.

Comment: Hey @SalmanKhan I added two more methods on how to accomplice the thing that you wish.

Comment: Thanks @Ketvo, you save my day. I will try this and let you know if there will be any problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the request returns an empty result, check whether the used Access Token contains the `user_photos` permission:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/photos#readperms

You can inspect the Acces Token via

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#debug

Request:

```
GET /debug_token?
 input_token={input-token}&
 access_token={access-token}
```